# Show that convolution satisfies partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convolution

> Consider the equation $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$ for a function $u(x,t)$ with initial value $$u(x,0)=f(x).$$ Let $u(x,t)=f(x)\ast\left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\dfrac{(at+x)^2}{4t}}\right)$, and suppose that $f\in L^1$. Show that $u(x,t)$ satisfies the equation above for $t>0,x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The function $u(x,t)$ has a convolution operation. How can I take its derivative with respect to $t$ or to $x$?

Comment: $(f*g)' = (f')*g = f*(g')$.  Here prime means differentiate with respect to $x$.  You show this by differentiating under the integral sign.  In your case you can make this argument rigorous.  Differentiating with respect to $t$ will be a bit easier.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith So you mean I can take the derivative of just $f$, or of just $g$, and still get the same answer?

Comment: Yes.  Because $f*g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-y) g(y) \, dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) g(x-y) \, dy$.  Differentiate with respect to $x$ under the integral, and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Okay, but to differentiate under the integral, I need to use [Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), which requires to show that $f(y)g(x-y)$ and $f(y)g'(x-y)$ are continuous. But here we don't have continuity assumption on $f$.

Comment: But $g$ is very differentiable.  Try to directly construct a proof that you can differentiate under the integral sign, by using Lebesgue's dominated convergence.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith For that I would need the difference quotient $\left|\frac{f(y)(g(r-y)-g(s-y))}{r-s}\right|$ to be dominated by an integrable function, right? We know $f\in L^1$, but I'm not sure how to deal with the term $g(r-y)-g(s-y)$

Comment: I think you can do it.  $g$ is a very nice function.  Find some crude upper bound.